# Need help on passing data from jsp to servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Im currently new in java ee. I need help on how to pass my data from jsp to my servlet to fil up my query. Whenever i run, the error is being catch and i print out the exception. It says java.null.exception.. I couldn't find out where my error is..pls help me... thanks..

Here is my code:

UpdateProductServlet.java

```
    try {
        String description = request.getParameter("description");
        float price = Float.parseFloat(request.getParameter("price"));
        String size = request.getParameter("size");
        int aisle_id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("aisle"));
        int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));

        ProductsDao productsDao = new ProductsDao();
        productsDao.updateProduct(description, price, size, aisle_id, id);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        out.println(e);
    }
```

and my ProductDao.java

```
public void updateProduct(String description, float price, String size, int aisle_id, int id) 
        throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    String sql = "UPDATE products "
            + "SET description = ?, price = ?, size = ?, aisle_id = ? "
            + "WHERE id = ? ";

    try {
        conn = ConnectionFactory.getConnection();
        stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        stmt.setString(1, description);
        stmt.setFloat(2, price);
        stmt.setString(3, size);
        stmt.setInt(4, aisle_id);
        stmt.setInt(5, id);
        stmt.executeUpdate();

    } finally {
        if (conn != null) {
            conn.close();
        }

        if (stmt != null){
            stmt.close();
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my ProductById.jsp

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
    <script>
        function functionEdit()
        {
            document.getElementById("edit").type="hidden";
            document.getElementById("update").type="button";
            document.getElementById("delete").type="hidden";
            document.getElementById("cancel").type="button";

            document.getElementById("description").disabled="";
            document.getElementById("size").disabled="";
            document.getElementById("price").disabled="";
            document.getElementById("select").disabled="";
        }

        function functionUpdateRecord(){
            if(confirm('Update existing record?')){
                document.location.href="/MachineProblemWebApp/UpdateProductServlet";
                alert('Update success!');
                document.location.href="/MachineProblemWebApp/GetAllProductsServlet";

            }else{ 
                alert('No changes have been made!');
            }

        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table border="0">
        <tr>
            <td>id: </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="id" id="id" value="${product.id}" disabled="disabled"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Description: </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="description" id="description" value="${product.description}" disabled="disabled"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Aisle </td>
            <td><select name="aisle" disabled="disabled" id="select">
                    <c:forEach var="aisle" items="${aisles}" >
                        <option value="${aisle.id}" ${(aisle.id==product.aisle.id)?"selected" : ""}>${aisle.description}</option>
                    </c:forEach>
                </select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Size: </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="size" id="size" value="${product.size}" disabled="disabled"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Price: </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="price" id="price" value="${product.price}" disabled="disabled"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="button" name="edit" id="edit" onClick="functionEdit()" value="Edit" >
                <input type="hidden" name="update" id="update" onClick="functionUpdateRecord()"value="Update">
                <input type="button" name="delete" id="delete" value="Delete">
                <input type="hidden" name="cancel" id="cancel" value="Cancel"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>
```

is this the stack trace? posted in Apache Tomcat Log?

```
Dec 10, 2012 7:38:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [UpdateProductServlet] in context with path     [/MachineProblemWebApp] threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1008)
at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:452)
at grocerific.ui.UpdateProductServlet.processRequest(UpdateProductServlet.java:45)
at grocerific.ui.UpdateProductServlet.doGet(UpdateProductServlet.java:75)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Dec 10, 2012 9:36:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextDestroyed()
Dec 10, 2012 9:36:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextDestroyed()
Dec 10, 2012 9:36:46 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
Dec 10, 2012 9:36:46 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
Dec 10, 2012 9:36:46 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache', 'org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache@8a47d9')
```

Comment: can you post your stack trace ?

Comment: @invariant hi.. is this the stack trace?

Comment: It looks like one of your calls to request.getParameter("whatever") is not finding the parameter you passed (or you forgot to pass it.)  I'm guessing "price" because it's bombing on a FloatingDecimal thing.  Check your input as it comes in and verify you're getting what you expect.

Comment: There's something you're trying to process in your servlet that comes as a null value, so the method applied on it fails and throw an exception. Could you debug your application to check that all the parameters from the request are not null (so parseint() won't fail)?

Comment: @LloydLiongson yes it is:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you try to pass the data whit:
`document.location.href="/MachineProblemWebApp/UpdateProductServlet";`

and it is not possible, because this line just redirect to "UpdateProductServlet" without sending the data.

you need to use the form tag to submit data.

in the link below you can see how to set the form tag:
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Answer (score 0):

the stacktrace tells you where the error is:

```
at grocerific.ui.UpdateProductServlet.processRequest(UpdateProductServlet.java:45)
```

I guess its this line

```
float price = Float.parseFloat(request.getParameter("price"));
```

the string you pass to parseFloat is not a float. it might be "" or "1,0" instead of "1.0" or similar.

From an architectural point of view you are totally on the wrong track. JSP is outdated and known to have many many many problems you are just at the beginning of a very painful path.

Look at using velocity instead of JSP. Better to research some web app frameworks. There are some dealing with form handling very well.